# word - how to not add styles to quick styles gallery when pasting text (without using the "paste text only" option)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, styles

I am using Word 2013 and I have the following problem.

When I paste text from an old document A with old styles in a nice clean document with custom styles in the quick styles gallery, I end up with the old styles in the clean quick styles gallery as well.

Of course, I can just use "paste as plain text", but I cannot teach many of my colleagues that (and I also cannot change the default paste option in Word on there computer) ;-(

Therefore, I am looking for a way to set up my .dotm template in such a way that stlyes will never be copied to that document!

Please help if you see any way to do what I have described.

Thank you and best regards,
Paolo